# How to assign appriori algorithm on data part by part?

Tags: python, split, bigdata, dask, apriori

I want to assign appriori method on my data has more than 1 millions rows. But I get this error:

> unable to allocate 79.4 gib for an array with shape (3741, 2, 1424744) and data type int64

I use dask library instead of pandas but it didn't work;
Now I want to split my data to several parts and then assign appriori and finally merge the results.
Is it possible? what is your suggestion?

Comment: It is probably possible, but the description of the problem is too broad at this point. Are you dealing with arrays? Do you want to apply the function on blocks of array/rolling/row-based? It would be great if you can provide these details or a minimal code example (pseudocode is OK).

Comment: type of data is dataframe ! I load a csv file that size is about 1 GB.